# Has the Roslyn compiler been integrated into the Mono project?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I've been rather interested in C# and Mono since Microsoft announced that it was open sourcing .Net. I was wondering how much influence this decision has had over the Mono project? I'm assuming it now means there isn't any potential danger of Microsoft trying to shut down the project anymore (if they had wanted)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes Roslyn has been integrated.

From the article [Mono and Roslyn](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2014/Apr-09.html), which was written by one of the Mono maintainers:

> At BUILD, [we showed Roslyn running on Mono](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/KEY02). If you want to run your own copy of Roslyn today, you need to use both a fresh version of Mono, and apply a handful of patches to Roslyn.
>
> ...
>
> Our goal is to keep track of Roslyn as it is being developed, and when it is officially released, to bundle Roslyn's compilers with Mono.

Comment: To be clear, Roslyn isn't shipping with Mono *yet*, the mcs compiler is still the default (and will probably be for some time).

Comment: @AlexanderKöplinger is it included now?

Comment: @PixxlMan yes it's shipping since Mono 5.0: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#c-compiler