# Using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis / Roslyn on Mono

Tags: c#, mono, roslyn

I'm trying to run a simple line in Mono, using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis:

```
var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
```

But the problem is that it seems that it can't load roslyn libraries because we are using Mono:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:GetTypes (System.Reflection.Assembly,bool)
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/Assembly.cs:405 
  at System.Reflection.Assembly+<>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () [0x00021] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/Assembly.cs:999 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[TSource,TResult].MoveNext () [0x00078] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs:282 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable+<SelectManyIterator>c__Iterator2`2[TSource,TResult].MoveNext () [0x0009a] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs:424 
  at System.Composition.TypedParts.TypedPartExportDescriptorProvider..ctor (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] types, System.Composition.Convention.AttributedModelProvider attributeContext) [0x00049] in <c909a8424f424533a07db3f5e57b744b>:0 
  at System.Composition.Hosting.ContainerConfiguration.CreateContainer () [0x00042] in <c909a8424f424533a07db3f5e57b744b>:0 
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Host.Mef.MefHostServices.Create (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] assemblies) [0x00019] in <947408acdcbc4eba93cdb6a19d92fcd1>:0 
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Host.Mef.DesktopMefHostServices.get_DefaultServices () [0x00011] in <2ba3a08d4fe0467c8c54c8bc37c61987>:0 
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.MSBuildWorkspace.Create (System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] properties) [0x00000] in <2ba3a08d4fe0467c8c54c8bc37c61987>:0 
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.MSBuildWorkspace.Create () [0x00000] in <2ba3a08d4fe0467c8c54c8bc37c61987>:0 
  at UTQGValidatorPluginCSharp.Program.CountProject (System.String solutionPath) [0x00001] in /Users/s/projects/xo/devfactory-utqg-csharp/src/UTQGValidatorPluginCSharp/Program.cs:31 
  at UTQGValidatorPluginCSharp.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00052] in /Users/s/projects/xo/devfactory-utqg-csharp/src/UTQGValidatorPluginCSharp/Program.cs:25 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:GetTypes (System.Reflection.Assembly,bool)
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/Assembly.cs:405 
  at System.Reflection.Assembly+<>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () [0x00021] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/Assembly.cs:999 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[TSource,TResult].MoveNext () [0x00078] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs:282 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable+<SelectManyIterator>c__Iterator2`2[TSource,TResult].MoveNext () [0x0009a] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs:424 
  at System.Composition.TypedParts.TypedPartExportDescriptorProvider..ctor (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] types, System.Composition.Convention.AttributedModelProvider attributeContext) [0x00049] in <c909a8424f424533a07db3f5e57b744b>:0 
  at System.Composition.Hosting.ContainerConfiguration.CreateContainer () [0x00042] in <c909a8424f424533a07db3f5e57b744b>:0 
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Host.Mef.MefHostServices.Create (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] assemblies) [0x00019] in <947408acdcbc4eba93cdb6a19d92fcd1>:0 
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Host.Mef.DesktopMefHostServices.get_DefaultServices () [0x00011] in <2ba3a08d4fe0467c8c54c8bc37c61987>:0 
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.MSBuildWorkspace.Create (System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] properties) [0x00000] in <2ba3a08d4fe0467c8c54c8bc37c61987>:0 
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.MSBuildWorkspace.Create () [0x00000] in <2ba3a08d4fe0467c8c54c8bc37c61987>:0 
  at UTQGValidatorPluginCSharp.Program.CountProject (System.String solutionPath) [0x00001] in /Users/s/projects/xo/devfactory-utqg-csharp/src/UTQGValidatorPluginCSharp/Program.cs:31 
  at UTQGValidatorPluginCSharp.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00052] in /Users/s/projects/xo/devfactory-utqg-csharp/src/UTQGValidatorPluginCSharp/Program.cs:25
```

But according with [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552190/has-the-roslyn-compiler-been-integrated-into-the-mono-project), Roslyn was completely integrated into Mono.

Is there any way to get it working on Mono? If yes, how should I do this?

Comment: I don't know that anyone has used MSBuildWorkspace on mono before.  The *compiler* is definitely integrated, and other parts of the workspace layer are used in MonoDevelop, but I'm not sure about MSBuildWorkspace.

Comment: Probably you should try to compile Mono 4.8 from source and see if it helps. Visual Studio for Mac is based on that.

Comment: @LexLi just as a question, what would be the difference if I compile Mono from sources?

Thanks!

Comment: @SergioFigueras Mono 4.8 is in Alpha, so I guess you won't have it easily without compiling from source.

Comment: Removed the rider tag. JetBrains Rider does not use Roslyn but ReSharper on Mono, so I don't think that's related.